# Spring boot jackson parser Null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am getting Null pointer exception while executing this line :
`mapper.readTree(..)` in spring boot application.
Application code where it is occurring is:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class JsonCompare {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        private ArrayList<String> newfileerror = new ArrayList<>();

        static {
            mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS, true);
        }


           public ArrayList<String> compare(String json1, String json2) throws IOException {
                    //convert string to node, convert to sorted string, and back to node!!:
                    JsonNode node1 = mapper.readTree(mapper.writeValueAsString(mapper.treeToValue(mapper.readTree(json1), Object.class)));
                    JsonNode node2 = mapper.readTree(mapper.writeValueAsString(mapper.treeToValue(mapper.readTree(json2), Object.class)));
                    compareNodes(node1, node2, "/");
                    return newfileerror;
        }
}
```

The logs for NPException is given below:

```
2018-07-24 13:00:09,027 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
2018-07-24 13:00:16,129 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/compare]
2018-07-24 13:00:16,129 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /compare
2018-07-24 13:00:16,130 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView co.nat.tool.controllers.JSONCompareController.compare(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,co.nat.tool.beans.TransformationDetails,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.lang.Exception]
2018-07-24 13:00:16,130 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'JSONCompareController'
2018-07-24 13:00:16,132 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor - Skip CORS processing: request is from same origin
2018-07-24 13:00:16,153 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults - Not strongly caching class [co.nat.tool.beans.TransformationDetails] because it is not cache-safe
2018-07-24 13:00:17,136 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView co.nat.tool.controllers.JSONCompareController.compare(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,co.nat.tool.beans.TransformationDetails,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.lang.Exception]: java.lang.NullPointerException
2018-07-24 13:00:17,139 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView co.nat.tool.controllers.JSONCompareController.compare(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,co.nat.tool.beans.TransformationDetails,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.lang.Exception]: java.lang.NullPointerException
2018-07-24 13:00:17,146 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView co.nat.tool.controllers.JSONCompareController.compare(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,co.nat.tool.beans.TransformationDetails,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.lang.Exception]: java.lang.NullPointerException
2018-07-24 13:00:17,150 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:889)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2551)
        at co.nat.tool.cma1.JsonCompare.compare(JsonCompare.java:31)
```

when application is trying to execute method "mapper.readTree" it gives me this exception. I didn't get it why this exception is occurring as I am new to this spring boot.
I have tried many things(adding configuration for jackson for spring boot for serialization feature as it is being mapped in code) but they are not working.

Spring boot configuration is given below:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;


@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>{

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JacksonConfiguration() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS, true);
      }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong and what should I need to implement to resolve this issue.
My task is to migrate the web application(Already working) to spring boot application so I cant change the java code as it is working before. My thought is add configuration to spring boot config file as provided above.

Comment: Can you tell us the json you are trying to deserialize? And why are you doing that: **mapper.readTree(mapper.writeValueAsString(mapper.treeToValue(mapper.readTree(json1), Object.class)))**?!?!?! you are converting the same object multiple times, it's equivalent to **mapper.readTree(json1)**

Comment: @TheOni To convert a JsonNode tree into a string with sorted field keys. it is similar to this: private String convertNode(final JsonNode node) throws JsonProcessingException {
    final Object obj = mapper.treeToValue(node, Object.class);
    final String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    return json;
}